# Conversor temperatura

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un conversor de temperaturas de grados celcius a fahrenheit y viceversa en PHP pero haga lo que haga, siempre me hace el calculo de farenheit a celcius aunque en el IF le dejo bien claro que criterios tiene que cumplir y aun asi me devuelve la respuesta de: `"La temperatura de ºC a ºF es de: " . ceil($converted);` aunque marque la opcion para convertir de farenheith a celcius

¿Donde está el fallo?

temperature-conversion.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Conversor temperatura</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="temp-calculator.php" method="POST">
        Temperatura <input type="text" name="temp" placeholder="34">
        <br>
        °C<input type="radio" name="unidad" value="btn-celcius">
        °F<input type="radio" name="unidad" value="btn-fahrenheit">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

temp-calculator.php

```
<?php

if (isset($POST["enviar"]) && $POST["unidad"]) {
    //celcius to faren
    $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    $converted = ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
    echo "La temperatura de ºF a ºC es de: " . ceil($converted);
} else {
    //faren to celcius
    $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    $converted = ($temp * 5) / 9 + 32;
    echo "La temperatura de ºC a ºF es de: " . ceil($converted);
}
```

Comment: lo mejor seria que el input de Celsius y  Fahrenheit  no tuvieran el mismo name, ya que lo que estas haciendo es comparar si hay unidades y los dos se llaman unidades, haz un if para el input de Celsius con el name Celsius y un else if con  Fahrenheit  para el input de  Fahrenheit

Comment: La idea esta bien pero, si lo hago asi son dos radios diferentes y ambos quedan marcados al hacer click en ambos, de esta otra manera queda uno de los dos marcados

Comment: if (isset($POST["enviar"])) {
 if ($POST["unidad"] == 'btn-celsius') {
     <codigo-de-conversion-a-fahrenheit)
} else {
   <el resto del codigo>
}
}

Comment: Nope, se queda en blanco la pagina

Comment: En PhP la variable $Post es $_POST, pruebas y me dices, a mi ya me funciona

Comment: Para `"enviar"` usaste `isset()`, pero no hiciste lo mismo para `"unidad"`.

Comment: Lo que menciona David Gonzalo es erróneo, en los inputs de tipo radio es valido ponerles el mismo nombre ya que solo tomará el valor del que tenga el atributo **checked**.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en la primer condición le estas indicando que si **$_POST['unidad']** esta definido y **$_POST["unidad"]** contiene un valor.

Esto hará que la mayoría de los casos sea verdadero, a no ser que envíes la petición sin esta variable.

La modificación que yo haría sería en ***temp-calculator.php***

```
<?php
 
  $temp = $_POST['temp'];

  if ($_POST["unidad"] == 'btn-celcius') {
    //celcius to faren
    $converted = ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
    echo "La temperatura de ºF a ºC es de: " . ceil($converted);
  }else{
   //faren to celcius
    $converted = ($temp * 5) / 9 + 32;
    echo "La temperatura de ºC a ºF es de: " . ceil($converted);
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así:

```
    <?php

if ( $_POST['unidad']=="btn_celsius") {
    //celcius to faren
    $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    $converted = ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
    echo "La temperatura de ºF a ºC es de: " . ceil($converted);
} else {
    //faren to celcius
    $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    $converted = ($temp * 5) / 9 + 32;
    echo "La temperatura de ºC a ºF es de: " . ceil($converted);
}
```

Cambios:
El isset("enviar") no hace falta porque no usas su valor y si no ha sido pulsado no se ejecuta el php.
$POST-> $_POST
Igualo al value que tiene el botón para saber cuál variable devuelve, así sabes cuál botón es, aunque recomiendo cambiar los nombres de los botones a lo que tienes en su valor y poner otro valor.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos en tu código preguntas si existe $POST["enviar"], esto esta bien, el detalle es que luego preguntas si existe el radio botón (esto siempre será cierto), lo que necesitas según la lógica del radio botón es preguntar cual escogió el usuario y esto se hace con el valor del radio boton (btn-celcius= si quieres convertir a celsius y btn-fahrenheit para fahrenheit) de alli que el cambio seria

```
<?php
//  hacer el cambio 
if (isset($POST["enviar"])){
    //simplificando
     $temp = $_POST['temp'];
    if ($_POST["unidad"] == 'btn-celcius') {
        //celcius to faren
        $converted = ($temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
        echo "La temperatura de ºF a ºC es de: " . ceil($converted);
    } else {
         //faren to celcius
         $converted = ($temp * 5) / 9 + 32;
         echo "La temperatura de ºC a ºF es de: " . ceil($converted);
    }
}
```